# Print the maximum element with their index position

Tags: java

I'm printing the maximum element in the array with their index. I tried this.

```
int[] a = {10,20,30,40,40};
int index = 0;
int max = a[0];
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    if(a[i] > max)
    {
         max = a[i];
         index = i;
    }
}
System.out.print(max + " " + index);
```

This prints " 40 3". But I need "40 3 40 4". How can I change the code to print both maximum element 40 with their index?

Comment: You'll need a place to store those indices; a single `int` won't do the job.

Comment: Inside your for loop, you test whether the current item is strictly superior to the previous maximum. You also need to test whether it is equal to the previous maximum and take appropriate actions. Looks like you will also need `index`  to be a list rather than a single integer since you want it to store the multiple indexes that can correspond to the maximum value.

Comment: As an alternative to storing the elements and printing them later you could use 2 loops: one to determine the maximum value and another one to check each element and if it is the maximum value you print it along with the current index (in that case the condition to print would be `if(a[i] == max)`. If the array is already sorted you can skip the first loop and take the highest value from the last element or iterate backwards until you hit a lower element (that would give you "40 4 40 3" though unless you build a result string first and print it at the end).

Comment: Maybe make your index a string and add something like `else if(a[i] == max){ index += " " + i; }` after your greater than check. Then you can split your index string based on the spaces to grab each individual index for printing. One way to go about it anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the max value and check the array for it e.g.

```
int[] a = {10, 20, 30, 40, 40};
int max = Arrays.stream(a).max().getAsInt();
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i] == max) {
        System.out.print(max + " " + i);
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to find all the max values and also store them in a way you can reuse them later you can use a `Map` with the `max` and `index` set as the `Value` and `Key` respectively.  Below is one way to implement this:

```
    //Max is the value, Key is the index
    Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();

    int [] a={10,20,30,40,40};

    int max=a[0];

    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        if(a[i] >= max)
        {
            max=a[i];
            //If the value is not inside the map, empty the map
            if (!m.containsValue(max))
            {
                m.clear();
            }
            //Place the value into the map
            m.put(i, max);
        }
    }
    System.out.print(m.toString());
```

This will output (you can change the way you print to anything to want):

```
{3=40, 4=40}
```